# TaskFactory & TaskScheduler for ValueTasks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, valuetask

I'm looking to gain control over how ValueTasks are invoked; specifically, I'm looking to

1. Force their invocation and all potential continuations onto a specific thread, and
2. Execute additional logic for each synchronous chunk of them (in case they are actually async)

For regular Task<T>, I can do all of that through TaskFactory and TaskScheduler.

Is there any equivalent for those specific classes for ValueTasks that work *without having to convert them to full-on Tasks*?

Or maybe any differently named classes that would expose a similar, maybe smaller subset of TaskFactory/TaskScheduler functionality for ValueTasks?

I know ValueTask functionality is intentionally constraint by design, however it feels like there "should" be something to at least control scheduling of them in some basic way. I have yet to find such a thing in the framework though.

Comment: ValueTask is intended for use with `await` (and should be `awaited` once only, ideally straight away). Continuations are scheduled onto a suitable thread by `await` (which may capture the ambient `SynchronizationContext`, depending on `ConfigureAwait`). You rarely ever need `TaskFactory` / `TaskScheduler` when `await` is being used -- they're more-or-less a relic of pre-C# 5 TPL code

Comment: `Task`s come in two flavors, delegate-based tasks and promise-style tasks. The delegate-based tasks are associated with a delegate, and they complete when the delegate is complete. These tasks can be scheduled with a `TaskScheduler`. The promise-style tasks cannot be scheduled, because they are not associated with runnable code. Are you searching for a mechanism that produces delegate-based `ValueTask`s? What would be the benefit of such a mechanism, assuming that these `ValueTask`s could not be completed upon creation, so they would never be cheap wrappers of an already known result?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes that's right, delegate-based creation. I'm probably missing something here, but why would they not be completeable on creation? E.g. say some dummy producer looks like Func<ValueTask<int>> = () => new ValueTask<int>(123);

Comment: Because if it's completed upon creation then it was not associated with a delegate to begin with. So it's either delegate-based, or completeable upon creation. It can't be both.

Comment: Btw the example you gave `Func<ValueTask<int>> = () => new ValueTask<int>(123);` is not an example of a delegate-based `ValueTask`. It's an example of a `ValueTask`-producing delegate. It's something quite different!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks, my confusion probably lies therein. Correct me where I go wrong, my train of thought was/is: Task-producing delegates allow to schedule tasks on a given scheduler. A ValueTask producing delegate would/should allow the same, but save the object/heap allocation of the Task object itself, in case the delegate producing the ValueTask synchronously produces a completed ValueTask

Comment: I think that you are over-complicating things. A delegate-based task is something quite simple. There is a delegate like `() => 13`, and a task that is associated with this delegate. The return value of the delegate is surfaced as the `Result` of the task. When you talk about delegates that produce `ValueTask`s, potentially asynchronously, then you enter the realm of the mind-boggling nested tasks. Like `Task<ValueTask<int>>` for example. You could increase further the complexity by adding more levels of nesting, but at the end it's the outer-most task that matters here.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm beginning to think it's over-complicated too ;-) I had a look at ValueTask's GetAwaiter for a bit. I might be able to cover these requirements with a custom synchronization context, but not in all scenarios. My personal summary so far is: Async await is obviously tremendously great. But for reliable, absolutely fine-grain flow control, it unfortunately doesn't seem to be quite adequate